# Бегущая строка

Tags: javascript

Какой будет код у бегущей строки с текстом "Здесь!"?
Все на Javascript И HTML

Comment: а просто на html не пойдёт?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<MARQUEE>Здесь!</MARQUEE>
```

Все на Javascript и HTML.

Answer (score 4):

1. `<marquee>Здесь!</marquee>` Плохой вариант ибо [см. w3.org](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/marquee)
2. CSS3 overflow-style не поддерживается ни одним браузером, и вообще, прямо скажем, не совсем то, что нужно.
3. [The Silky Smooth Marquee](http://remysharp.com/2008/09/10/the-silky-smooth-marquee/) jQuery плагин

В общем варианты есть, но бегущие строки маздай!

Answer (score 0):

устаревший ...

```
<marquee direction="left|right|up|down">Здесь!</marquee>
```

http://developertut.com/html/html-tag-marquee

Comment: чем данный ответ отличается от уже принятого?

Comment: На нашем не принято спустя годы повторять те же самые ответы, чуть поменяв текст. Формально ваш ответ не считается нарушением, но я бы рекомендовал в будущем стараться избегать подобных действий. Вопросов на сайте много -- есть куда потратить силы с бОльшей пользой и для вас и для сообщества.